# performance and load testing with LoadNinja or should I choose other tool?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing

I am in college for Software QA. Teacher briefly introduced us to LoadNinja using their trial version which is expired now. I want to have some projects on my Github to show potential employers that I have some idea about performance testing and load testing. I did search through LoadNinja documentation but didn't find anything about how to upload projects to Github? Should I use LoadNinja or try find other tool which is free ? May be pick a tool from mentioned in this article https://www.softwaretestingmagazine.com/knowledge/free-web-load-testing-services/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/loadninja/docs/general-info/about.html):

> LoadNinja is a **cloud-based** load testing and performance testing platform for web applications and web services.

So I think your test scripts are being stored in the cloud, you won't be able to share the test scripts with the potential employers unless they have a LoadNinja account.

It's possible to use [REST API](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/smartbear/loadninja/1.0) to kick off the test, but in that case you will need to share your API key which is a big security hole.

I would recommend considering choosing another testing tool, there is a number of [free and open source load testing tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which are even more popular and powerful like:

- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Locust](https://locust.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

which store test scripts in forms of files on the file system and the files can be added under any version control system